# PartCover and multiple TargetArgs

Tags: partcover

I need to load coverage report from multiples test source, but if I set multiple dlls (two of them test the same class) in TargetArgs, the coverage data is overwritten with the results of the last dll.

How can I add the results from multiples dll testing the same class?

Here is an example of my partcover config file

```
<PartCoverSettings>
  <Target>c:\NUnit\nunit-console.exe</Target> 
  <TargetWorkDir>c:\MyProject\Testing</TargetWorkDir> 
  <TargetArgs>ApplicationServices.Test.dll Integration.Test.dll</TargetArgs> 
  <Rule>+[MyProject.*]*</Rule> 
  <Rule>-[*.Test]*</Rule> 
</PartCoverSettings>
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

That should actually work. I do the same - run multiple test assemblies and get coverage output. I do it from the command line rather than config file though.

Have you double checked that your rules are correct?

Comment: Hi

The problem isn't run multiple test assemblies. That works, but the last assembly overwrite the coverage for the first, if the two assemblies cover the same class